# how call .exe file from <custom action /> with command arguments

Tags: c++, wix, arguments, windows-installer

I create custom action:

```
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" FileKey="FileKeyExe" ExeCommand="" Return="asyncNoWait"/>
```

and execute file after installation:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
 <Custom Action="LaunchApplication" After="InstallFinalize"></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

all work fine!

but I need run my .exe file with command arguments. how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send the exe command line arguments you need to include them in the ExeCommand field e.g.

```
 <CustomAction Id="ExecutingAwesomeness" ExeCommand="Awesome.exe -fireworks -parade" />
```

Comment: i try do this:

    <CustomAction
       Id="LaunchApplication"
       Directory="APPLICATIONFOLDER"
       ExeCommand="[APPLICATIONFOLDER]myApp.exe –myArg"
    Return="asyncNoWait" />

but a have error: unexpected parametr '-myArg'

Comment: what about to match your previous (which I should have replied with to start with) <CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" FileKey="FileKeyExe" ExeCommand="-myArg" Return="asyncNoWait"/>

Comment: solved my problem: <CustomAction Id="ExecutingAwesomeness" ExeCommand="parameter1 parameter2" /> thanks.